# mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lfl collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, makefile, flex-lexer

I am trying to execute `FLEX` program from the [Github](https://github.com/jayant141191/Compiler_Design_Project) on windows and I have installed `Flex` and `MingW` Compiler.

I have added below paths to Environmental variables

1. C:\MinGW\bin
2. C:\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin

After that, I trying to execute `make` command and I got the below output

```
g++ -g -Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=gnu++0x bison.o lex.o main.o -o mini_lang -lfl
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lfl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [mini_lang] Error 1
```

Below is `Makefile`

```
OBJ = bison.o lex.o main.o
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=gnu++0x

mini_lang:$(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o mini_lang -lfl

lex.o: lex.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c lex.c -o lex.o

lex.c: lex_final.l
    flex lex_final.l
    cp lex.yy.c lex.c

bison.o: bison.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c bison.c -o bison.o

bison.c: grammar.y
    bison -d -v grammar.y
    cp grammar.tab.c bison.c
    cmp -s grammar.tab.h tok.h || cp grammar.tab.h tok.h

main.o: main.cc
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c main.cc -o main.o

lex.o yac.o main.o: headers.h
lex.o main.o: tok.h


clean:
    rm -f *.o *~ lex.c lex.yy.c bison.c tok.h grammar.tab.c grammar.tab.h grammar.output mini_lang
```

Please, can anyone help me to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to find a different tutorial.

Either the flex distribution you installed does not include `libfl` or you did not add the path to `libfl` to the correct environment variable. You might try adding the path explicitly to the minilang rule, using a `-L` option before `-lfl`: `... -L /path/to/directory-containinglibfl -lfl`.

However, there is absolutely no need for `-lfl`, so the better solution is to just remove it from the `minilang` action, and add

```
%option noyywrap
```

to your flex input file. (That will prevent it from producing a scanner which calls `yywrap`, so you will not require the `yywrap` which is in `libfl`.)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the MinGW compiler, open *InstallationManager* and install this package:

```
mingw32-pthreads-w32
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using MingW+MSYS2, and for me the Flex library is located at `c:\msys32\usr\lib\libfl.a`.

Try searching for `libfl.a` in your MinGW folder tree, and use the `-L` compiler/linker flag, followed by the folder path where the library is located, to instruct the compiler/linker to look for `libfl.a` in that location.

For example:

`g++ -g -Wall -ansi -pedantic -std=gnu++0x bison.o lex.o main.o -o mini_lang -lfl -Lc:\msys32\usr\lib`